# PrettyPrinter - Print output on separate lines from the start and end bracket

Tags: python, pretty-print

Using something like:

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=...).pprint
```

Current output of `pp(my_list)`:

```
[   1,
    2,
    3]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

How might this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **json module**.

**Ex:**

```
import json
my_list = [1,2,3]
print(json.dumps(my_list, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    1, 
    2, 
    3
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also postprocess the string:

```
s = pprint.pformat(obj, indent=4)
s = s[0] + '\n' + s[1:-1] + '\n' + s[-1]
print(s)
```

This will work for simple lists and dicts, but not nested structures.

The json answer works for native datatypes, but if you have custom classes in your data structure json won't know how to serialize them.